# Converting a m x n matrix to a n*m x 3 matrix

Tags: r, matrix, distance

I currently have a matrix that is 479 x 729, and I would like to convert this matrix into a three column matrix such that the first column is the row entry of the original matrix, the second column is the column entry of the original matrix, and the third column is the value at that column and row entry.

Is there an easy way to do this? I have looked at the `reShape` function but have not figured out how to apply this here. The motivation for this is to be able to create a distance table for elements within the matrix that includes their location.

Comment: can you paste sample data?

Comment: What have you already tried? Where did you get stuck?  _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_. Please eee: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a better or more clever way, but this seems straight-forward and fast enough:

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(349191), 479, 729)

row_num <- as.vector(row(m))
col_num <- as.vector(col(m))
val <- as.vector(m)

new_m <- as.matrix(cbind(row_num, col_num, val))

dim(new_m)
# [1] 349191      3

head(new_m)
#      row_num col_num          val
# [1,]       1       1 1.0839690124
# [2,]       2       1 0.7363313818
# [3,]       3       1 0.0001195304
# [4,]       4       1 0.2123100877
# [5,]       5       1 0.1293427830
# [6,]       6       1 1.1773676868

tail(new_m)
#           row_num col_num         val
# [349186,]     474     729 -0.07942063
# [349187,]     475     729 -0.25694755
# [349188,]     476     729 -0.69421258
# [349189,]     477     729  1.24861689
# [349190,]     478     729  0.24377606
# [349191,]     479     729  0.49150676
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
library(reshape2)
melt(M)
```

where `M` is your matrix

Comment: This function doesn't seem to be part of the vanilla distribution of R (at least it's not in 3.2.3). Which package do you intend to refer to?